# Draw nodes and edges in network

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I just wrote python 3.4 code for creating a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) graph using Networkx.

The problem is that I can't access the dictionary values from within:

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(dag,
                       pos,
                       node_color=[node[1]['color'] for node in dag.nodes(data=True)], 
                       node_shape=[node[1]['shape'] for node in dag.nodes(data=True)])
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file_path = 'Demo.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

dag = nx.DiGraph()

for col in treatment_columns:
    dag.add_node(col, label='Treatment', color='blue', shape='ellipse')

for col in confounder_columns:
    dag.add_node(col, label='Confounder', color='green', shape='rectangle')

dag.add_node(outcome_column, label='Outcome', color='red', shape='ellipse')

pos = nx.spring_layout(dag)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(dag, pos, node_color=[node[1]['color'] for node in dag.nodes(data=True)], node_shape=[node[1]['shape'] for node in dag.nodes(data=True)])
nx.draw_networkx_labels(dag, pos, labels={node[0]: node[0] for node in dag.nodes(data=True)})
nx.draw_networkx_edges(dag, pos)

plt.axis('off')
plt.title("Causal DAG")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing seems to be related to how you're trying to access the values of dictionaries associated with the nodes in your Networkx DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph).

In your code, you're attempting to access the values of dictionaries associated with nodes using a syntax that might not be correct. You should be able to get the values of dictionaries associated with nodes like this:

```
node_colors = [data['color'] for node, data in dag.nodes(data=True)]
node_shapes = [data['shape'] for node, data in dag.nodes(data=True)]

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(dag, pos, node_color=node_colors, node_shape=node_shapes)
```

You need to extract the values of 'color' and 'shape' from the node data using data['color'] and data['shape'], respectively. Then you can pass these lists of colors and shapes directly to the nx.draw_networkx_nodes() function.

Make sure that treatment_columns, confounder_columns, and outcome_column are defined in your code appropriately, and that the nodes in your DAG actually have data associated with the keys 'color' and 'shape'. If not, you'll need to ensure you define this data before using it in the graph drawing. I hope this helps you Good day